# Adding static blocks to sitemap page

Tags: magento-1.9

The Sitemap page in Magento 1.9 is by default one column layout.
I changed it to a 3 columns layout by adding this to local.xml:

```
<catalog_seo_sitemap>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_seo_sitemap>
```

It works, however both left and right sidebar are empty and don't show the static blocks in them.
I found that in catalog.xml these are removed by default:

```
<catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
</catalog_seo_sitemap>
```

Now to bring them back I could:

1. Comment above code out in catalgo.xml. But I don't want to change Magento core files.
2. I could use Alan Storm's unremove plugin. Maybe, but I don't like to install too many plugins.

Now my qeuestion:

Is there any way to unrmove right and left for sitemap using the local.xml ?

Thanks

Comment: You could copy catalgo.xml to your local theme layout folder

Comment: can you use 1 column layout and where are want to show those cms block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be

Copy catalog.xml to local theme layout folder  (/app/design/frontend/default/{theme}/layout/catalog.xml)

Then delete

```
<catalog_seo_sitemap translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Seo Sitemap (Common)</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
</catalog_seo_sitemap>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative process :
 create `replicated of  3columns.phtml` and assign this layout file  only this catalog seo sitemap page.

```
<catalog_seo_sitemap>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns-relicated.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_seo_sitemap>
```

On `3columns-relicated.phtml` remove `$this->getChildHtml('right')` &&  `$this->getChildHtml('left')` and call your static block programmatically on